# Can't use specific Icons in imported flutter project

Tags: android-studio, flutter, icons

this might be a quick one.

I've imported a Flutter project which a colleague created via VS Code into Android Studio (via Git - Bitbucket).
(I've worked on another new Flutter project just this day.)
The problem is: some icons he used aren't found by the compiler for me.

Examples of working icons:

- Icons.pregnant_woman
- Icons.person
- Icons.calendar_today

Not working:

- Icons.qr_code
- Icons.biotech

Also, no matter in which file I'm in, there's a hint window above stating: `'Pub get' has not been run` and I get the option to run `get dependencies` (pub get) or `upgrade dependencies` (pub upgrade).

When I first imported the project, the compiler didn't even know what Flutter is. After I executed pub get the first time, most of the errors were gone. The only ones missing are the few icons. But the hint saying I didn't do pub get is still there which was never like this in my other projects.

What can I do?

Btw, `pub outdated` says `dev_dependencies: all up-to-date` and

> Dependencies are all on the latest resolvable versions.
> Newer versions, while available, are not mutually compatible.

Comment: Do you see any font file in the assets folder or is there any font [asset] import in pubspec.yaml?

Comment: @bluenile there's no font import yet, no. Only a few dependencies (intl, http, provider). But I just noticed there's the following in the dependencies: cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

Comment: Could you please provide the pubspec.yaml file? And also the output of flutter --version. You should also try to run the command: flutter packages get

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem a while ago. The way I managed to solve it is:

go to Vs code setting and search `flutter create` and disable `Flutter Create Offline`

[image]

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Turns out I changed some internal flutter file some while back and it wouldn't upgrade the flutter version automatically until I did "flutter upgrade -force".